# Hashmap updating for all keys if value is updated for a particular key

Tags: java, hashmap

I've a hashmap with key as integer and value as list of dates. I'm trying to update one of the value for a particular integer. Initially the dates will be same for all keys.

Now, I want to set one of the date as null to 101 key, when I update a particular key, its updated for all keys. Where am I doing wrong? Please suggest.

Here is my code

Initial the dates are set like this

```
   // Set dates to all records
   resultDate = [Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2018, Fri Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 9999] // Typo here 
   Set<Integer> records= parsedResults.keySet();
        if (records.size() > 0) {               
            for (Integer record: records) {
                dateMap.get(Integer.parseInt(record));
                dateMap.put(record,resultDate);
            }
        }
```

Then updating end date as null only for 101

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Date>> entry : dateMap.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getKey().equals(Integer.parseInt("101"))) {
                List<Date> dates = entry.getValue();
                if(null == effDate) {
                    dates.set(0, null);
                } else {
                    dates.set(0, effDate);          
                }
                if(null == endDate) {
                    dates.set(1, null); 
                } else {
                    dates.set(1, endDate);
                }
                dateMap.put(Integer.parseInt("101"), dates);                                        
            }
        }
```

Initial dateMap response

```
{101=[Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2018, Fri Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 9999], 102=[Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2018, Fri Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 9999], 103=[Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2018, Fri Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 9999]}
```

After when I update as null then,

```
{101=[Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2018, null], 102=[Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2018, null], 103=[Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2018, null]}
```

Comment: @Deadpool, I updated the code on how I'm setting the dates initially. I feel there is something wrong with the reference of the list of dates

Comment: exactly for every key you are pairing same value

Comment: @Deadpool, so where should I modify in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is for every key you are pairing same list object, in the for loop use `new ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` constructor to create new object every time

```
if (records.size() > 0) {               
        for (Integer record: records) {
            dateMap.get(Integer.parseInt(record));  //you can remove this line
            dateMap.put(record,new ArrayList(resultDate));
        }
    }
```

**public ArrayList(Collection c)**

> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

Comment: resultDate itself is an List object, so you want me to put new ArrayList of List again?

Comment: Why do we need this code --dateMap.get(Integer.parseInt(record));?? You are not initializing it any way?

Comment: yes you can remove the unwanted code, i'm just trying to fix issue that's it @Syed

Answer (score 0):

your values maybe use one list with diff alias

```
List one = new AraayList();
map.put("k1", one);
map.put("k2", one);
List alias = one;
map.put("k3", alias);
```

these values are use the same instance, when you update one, then other see the the changes.